# Checking Time using Excel VBA without date/time format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to ensure that the user of the tool only inserts valid time values. This input need to be numeric and not in datetime format. I understand that conditional formatting from the front-end would be a lot simpler, but a copy-paste action will overwrite the conditional formatting. So I've decided to write in a macro for it with the following logic : 
1) Input has to be in number format '0000'
2) The first 2 digits have to be lesser than 23 AND
3) The last 2 digits have to be lesser than 59

This is the code I have so far but it's not giving me the intended output. Where is the error or is there a more effective way of solving this?

```
Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "0000"

For count = 2 To (lastRow + 1)
If IsEmpty(Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & count).Value) = True Then
    Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
Else
    If (Left(Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & count).Text, 2)) > 23 Or (Right(Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & count).Text, 2)) > 59 Then
        Worksheets("SheetA").Range("A" & count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End If
Next count
```

Comment: Why can't I just type in **1** for 00:01:00??

Comment: it seems that if you are formatting your cells as numbers (instead of text) so you wont be able to get for example times less than 10. i.e 0923 will be displayed as 923. Better to have the value as text and then parse then in your code as integers

Comment: @Jeeped, Well I can't have the cell set to date time format. So it has to be a normal number/string in HHMM.. Not sure if I'm answering your question though

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key then. Try this ... why can't I type in 1, press enter and have the value converted to hh:mm or hhmm in an actual time value? A value in hhmm as an integer is useless.

Comment: @Vaishali convert cell values to Integer type `CInt` in If condition

Comment: For that matter, why can't I type in 61 and get a result of 0101 as real time? I'm honestly not trying to be disingenuous here. I'm merely trying to point you in a better direction by assuming the role of devil's advocate.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, I've amended the original post. All my inputs are in the Column A. I understand that it seems like using HHMM in integer format seems useless, but this is used as a further input to a different program where the time formatting screws up the transfer.

Comment: Hi @SNicolaou, so i'm trying a fix where I don't have to format the cells as a number and keep it as text. Will get back on how it turns out

Answer (score 2):

In a normal module create a procedure to format your number as text and test it's within the required range:

```
Public Sub TestNumber(Target As Range)

    Dim FormattedNumber As String

    'Return formatted "text" version of value.
    FormattedNumber = Format(Target, "0000")

    'Assume the value is correct and set the cell to "valid" colour.
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)

    'Validate the value - check it's length, that it's a number
    'and falls with the specified ranges.
    If Len(FormattedNumber) = 4 And IsNumeric(Val(FormattedNumber)) Then
        If Val(Left(FormattedNumber, 2)) < 0 Or Val(Left(FormattedNumber, 2)) > 23 Or _
         Val(Right(FormattedNumber, 2)) < 0 Or Val(Right(FormattedNumber, 2)) > 59 Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            'Remove if you don't want to reformat the number.
            Target.Value = Format(FormattedNumber, "00:00")
        End If
    Else
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

On each sheet you want to check numbers in column 1 add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rCell In Target
                TestNumber rCell
            Next rCell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The `Application.EnableEvents` lines are only required if you reformat the entered number at the end of the `TestNumber` procedure.  Not adding the command fires the `Change` event a second time with the reformatted number - which will return incorrect results, before firing again and eventually returning `00:00`.

**Edit:**
Have updated the `Change` event so it will work if more than one cell is changed (if a range of numbers are pasted in) and changed an `AND` to an `OR` in the `TestNumber` procedure (it was accepting *6000* previously).

**Edit again:**
If you want to check the number as entered remove the `FormattedNumber` variable and replace with `Target` and format the column as text so you don't lose the leading 0.

Comment: The range.text property will read the cell value as text with leading zeroes. If the cell number formatting has already been set to `0000` then left and right from the .Text shouldn't be an issue beyond converting the text to true numbers for numerical comparisons.

Comment: btw, did you ever figure out whether the input was in column A or column N? I've read the narrative a few times and Iit seems to contradict the code which also seems to contradict itself.

Comment: Good point with the `Text`.  I always forget the obvious.  Just a case of removing `FormattedNumber` and replace with `Target.Text`, but can't put value back as real time as the cell doesn't have that format.  I hadn't spotted the `A` or `N` column - I was wondering why check all values each time and need to check for minus values.

Comment: I seriously don't know. I've had a viable alternative answer sitting in draft for quite a while but the op hasn't resolved any of my comments to my satisfaction; the primary one is HHMM as an integer is useless so why not use real time?

Comment: On a side note, you should use a variable for the range i.e. `Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(Target, Columns(1))` and loop over the cells of it starting with `If Not irg Is Nothing Then` because `Target` could have cells outside of column `A`.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT Function (Worksheet / VBA)

The Excel LEFT function can be used both as a worksheet function and a VBA function. The LEFT function returns the specified number of characters in a text string, starting from the first or left-most character. Use this function to extract a sub-string from the left part of a text string. Syntax: LEFT(text_string, char_numbers). It is necessary to mention the text_string argument which is the text string from which you want to extract the specified number of characters. The char_numbers argument is optional (when using as a worksheet function), which specifies the number of characters to extract from the text string. The char_numbers value should be equal to or greater than zero; if it is greater than the length of the text string, the LEFT function will return the text string in full; if omitted, it will default to 1. While using as a VBA function, it is necessary to specify both the arguments, and if text_string contains Null, the function also returns Null.

If you want obtain your goal i have an alternative for you:
your input have to be a string after your control you convert the string in number if is a time else no conversation.

to convert string in number example:

```
Dim finalNumber As Integer
    If IsNumeric(myVar) Then
        finalNumber = CInt(myVar)
    Else
        finalNumber = 0
    End If
```

and limit input with this step 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/952-excel-cell-character-limit.html

Comment: Try to make your text more clear to make this a good answer (and be upvoted), like this it is really hard for the eyes to follow

Comment: Sorry @Pierre44, if i answer now...i am late,the first part my answer is been posted from Darren...control the lenght and if is numeric the target value...